# SSLHandshakeException: CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found. with valid certificate

Tags: android, ssl, certificate, okhttp, ca

I have an android application that uses an API. the base URL of my API is: "akazemib.rahkaran.ir"
I am using OkHttp client directly with this code:

```
new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .cookieJar(cookieJar)
            .connectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS)
            .build();
```

But I got SSLHandshake: CertPathValidatorException. the certificate that we use is valid and obtained from Certum Trusted Network CA like below:

[image]

I tried custom Trust Manager and SslFactory and add Certificate String manually and the problem is solved

`new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .cookieJar(cookieJar)
                .connectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS)
                .sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, trustManager)
                .hostnameVerifier(OkHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE)
                .build();`

```
String certString = ""
            + "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n" +
            "MIIF0jCCBLqgAwIBAgIQaoGIm2LXLNbBk72jLNf5LTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADCB\n" +
            "hTELMAkGA1UEBhMCUEwxIjAgBgNVBAoTGVVuaXpldG8gVGVjaG5vbG9naWVzIFMu\n" +
            "QS4xJzAlBgNVBAsTHkNlcnR1bSBDZXJ0aWZpY2F0aW9uIEF1dGhvcml0eTEpMCcG\n" +
            "A1UEAxMgQ2VydHVtIERvbWFpbiBWYWxpZGF0aW9uIENBIFNIQTIwHhcNMTcxMDEx\n" +......
```

But how can I fix this SSLHandshake error without adding a certificate manually? is something wrong with CA? or intermediate certificate on the server-side?

Comment: *" or intermediate certificate on the server-side?"* - exactly: an intermediate certificate is missing in the server setup. See the [SSLLabs report](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=akazemib.rahkaran.ir&s=5.160.199.65&latest).

Comment: thanks for the reply. this exactly what I am looking for.